# Inserting object properties in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have following Linq to entities statment.

```
var records = from c in db.l_rate_his
              select new testing { namec.l_rate.name, labo = c.rate};
```

I am trying to convert it to lambda expression. I have gotten this far

```
var records1 = db.l_rate_his.Include(p => p.labor_rate).ToArray();
```

How to complete the lambda expression to include the object properties?

Comment: As a side-note, you might want to take a look at the [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#. It would help make your code easier to read to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query

```
var records = from c in db.l_rate_his
              select new testing { namec.l_rate.name, labo = c.rate};
```

is equivalent to

```
var records = db.l_rate_his
                .Select(c => new testing { namec.l_rate.name, labo = c.rate });
```